Removing a XML child node with VBA
This is the VBA code I'm currently using to import an XML into my workbook (which works just fine):
Sub matomoImportXML()

Dim matomoXML As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set matomoXML = Workbooks.OpenXML(FileName:=matomo_xml, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

matomoXML.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy report.Sheets(matomo_data).Range("A1")
matomoXML.Close False

End Sub

And this is an example of the XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <row>
        <label>lp_total_pageviews=1 - my-website.com/please-verify-you-age-to-enter/ - Others</label>
        <nb_uniq_events_eventaction>118</nb_uniq_events_eventaction>
        <nb_uniq_events_eventcategory>118</nb_uniq_events_eventcategory>
        <nb_uniq_corehome_visitip>118</nb_uniq_corehome_visitip>
        <level>3</level>
        <Events_EventAction>lp_total_pageviews=1</Events_EventAction>
        <Events_EventCategory>my-website.com%2Fplease-verify-you-age-to-enter%2F</Events_EventCategory>
        <is_summary>1</is_summary>
        <CoreHome_VisitIp>Others</CoreHome_VisitIp>
    </row>
    <row>
        <label>lp_total_clicks=1 - my-website.com/please-verify-you-age-to-enter-rs/ - xxxx:1009:b00a:6fd8:d937:5eb2:7563:de56</label>
        <nb_uniq_events_eventaction>3</nb_uniq_events_eventaction>
        <nb_uniq_events_eventcategory>3</nb_uniq_events_eventcategory>
        <nb_uniq_corehome_visitip>3</nb_uniq_corehome_visitip>
        <level>3</level>
        <Events_EventAction>lp_total_clicks=1</Events_EventAction>
        <Events_EventCategory>my-website.com%2Fplease-verify-you-age-to-enter-rs%2F</Events_EventCategory>
        <CoreHome_VisitIp>XXXX:1009:b00a:6fd8:d937:5eb2:7563:de56</CoreHome_VisitIp>
    </row>
</result>

Now, before I import and copy it to my workbook, I have to loop through the XML and delete the child node <is_summary>some value</is_summary> completely (if it exist).
I've been trying out multiple solutions I found online, but so far unsuccessful.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It is easy to achieve via XSLT transformation. Are you open to it?

@YitzhakKhabinsky Whatever works, sure. But can't I just modify the XML, before importing it?

Please, try the next way:
Sub testRemoveXMLNode()
   'it needs a reference to 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'
   Dim xmlPath As String, XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, n As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
   
   xmlPath = "Your XML file full name" 'use the real name
   Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   XDoc.Load (xmlPath)
   Debug.Print XDoc.XML & vbCrLf & "___"
    Dim strTag As String: strTag = "is_summary"
    
    For Each n In XDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
        recursiveTagSrc n, strTag
    Next n

    Debug.Print XDoc.XML 'just to see the result
    'it can be saved as another XML document or overwrite the original XML file (xDoc.Save xmlPath)...
End Sub
Sub recursiveTagSrc(n As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode, strTag As String)
    Dim Nd As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    If n.HasChildNodes Then
        For Each Nd In n.ChildNodes
            If Nd.HasChildNodes Then recursiveTagSrc Nd, strTag
            If Nd.nodeName = strTag Then
                n.RemoveChild Nd
            End If
        Next Nd
    End If
End Sub


Hi, @faneDuru. Thank you!
That seems to work out of the box.
One follow-up question, if you don't mind (forgive my ignorance - I'm new to VBA).
You commented: "It can be saved as another XML document"
Can I OVERWRITE the existing XML, based on your changes, so my import function which runs next gets the updated XML?

Of course, you can . I only wanted you to see it before doing that. To be sure that it works as yiu need.

@Faneduru Think you might remove brackets in XDoc.Load (xmlPath) 'cause no evaluation needed. Fyi posted an alternative via removals of found nodes in a nodelist

You need to pre-process XML file via XSLT transformation before loading/importing it.
The XSLT below is using a so called Identity Transform pattern.
One single line <xsl:template match="is_summary"/> prevents that XML element from being in the output XML file.
XSLT
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"
               encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!--Identity transform-->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="is_summary"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

VBA
Private Sub Transform(sourceFile, stylesheetFile, resultFile)

    Dim source As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim stylesheet As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim result As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    ' Load data.
    source.async = False
    source.Load sourceFile

    ' Load style sheet.
    stylesheet.async = False
    stylesheet.Load stylesheetFile

    If (source.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0) Then
       MsgBox ("Error loading source document: " & source.parseError.reason)
    Else
        If (stylesheet.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0) Then
            MsgBox ("Error loading stylesheet document: " & stylesheet.parseError.reason)
        Else
            ' Do the transform.
            source.transformNodeToObject stylesheet, result
            result.Save resultFile
        End If
    End If

End Sub


XSLT seems to be new land for many coders using xmldom only, so it's very positive to see a good example here +:)

And XSLT is available starting from 1999 onwards, quarter of a century.

The following function demonstrates an XMLDOM alternative to @FaneDuru 's working solution by

extracting a node list including only the relevant nodes via a simple XPath expression (here: "//is_summary" where the double slashes indicate a search at any hierarchy level - c.f. section b) and by
removing these findings directly via the RemoveChild method (c.f. section c)

instead of traversing all nodes one by one, thus minimizing the checks whether to remove or not.
Side note:
@Yitzhak-Khabinsky 's valid approach doesn't use XMLDOM methods for removal, but XSLT, a special-purpose language designed to transform original XML files (here by removing nodes via identity transform) according to various criteria.
Function cleanXML(ByVal xmlFilename As String, _
    ByVal DELNODE As String) _
    As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
'a) load src
    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xDoc.async = False
    xDoc.Load xmlFilename
'b) get nodelist
    Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Set nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//" & DELNODE)
'c) remove each node nodelist
    Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    For Each node In nodes
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild node
    Next
'd) return xml as object
    Set cleanXML = xDoc
End Function

Example call
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
'0) initial definitions
    Const DELNODE As String = "is_summary"
    Dim fn As String: fn = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\" & "Whatever.xml"
'1) get result with removed DELNODEs
    Dim result As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set result = cleanXML(fn, DELNODE)
'2) display result
    Debug.Print result.xml
    Debug.Print Format(Timer - t, "0.0 secs needed")
    
''3) save result to any destination filename
'    Dim destFn As String: destFn = fn  ' e.g. overwrite src
'    result.Save destFn
End Sub

